# Jquery en laravel, no funciona

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

Estoy intentando ligar Jquery a mi laravel, justo estoy aprendiendo ahora y tengo este trzoo de codigo para un index facilito:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>@yield('title', 'Default')  |Panel de Administración</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css') }}">
```

```
@include('admin.template.partials.nav')

<section>
    @yield('content')
</section>

<script src="{{ asset('plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('plugins/jquery/js/jquery-3.2.1.js') }}"></script>
```

Y la ruta de mi archvio es esta:

```
plugins/jquery/js/jquery-3.2.1.js
```

Que es justo la que pone en el, la ruta del `CSS` funciona perfectamente pero esta del `Jquery` no.

Estan dentro de la carpeta `public` la carpeta `plugins`

Comment: ¿Aparece algún error en la consola? Si no, ¿si haces `jQuery` (Q mayúscula es importante) recibes algún mensaje?

Comment: SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module  popper.js:2297
Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org)

Comment: Vale estoy investigando, y es, por que boostrap 4 ahora necesita popper para funcionar los menus despegables, pero estoy poniendole el archivo y sigue sin cogermelo digo que no lo hago bien

Answer (score 3):

Hay un error en el orden de los scripts, el orden tiene que ser

```
<script src="{{ asset('plugins/jquery/js/jquery-3.2.1.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Lo puse de esa manera, y sigue sin funcionar el `Jquery`. Tambien lo llame `jQuery`y nada

Comment: SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module  popper.js:2297
Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org)